# Python obtain maximum alignment between two lists of strings

Tags: python

We have two lists of numbered strings here:

```
list1=[[0, u'html'], [1, u'head'], [2, u'title'], [3, u'link'], [4, u'link'], [5, u'link'], [6, u'meta'], [7, u'meta'], [8, u'meta'], [9, u'meta'], [10, u'meta'], [11, u'meta'], [12, u'script'], [13, u'body'], [14, u'ul'], [15, u'li'], [16, u'a'], [17, u'li'], [18, u'a'], [19, u'li'], [20, u'a'], [21, u'li'], [22, u'a'], [23, u'div'], [24, u'a'], [25, u'div'], [26, u'div'], [27, u'form'], [28, u'fieldset'], [29, u'legend'], [30, u'input'], [31, u'input'], [32, u'label'], [33, u'input'], [34, u'input'], [35, u'ul'], [36, u'li'], [37, u'a'], [38, u'li'], [39, u'a'], [40, u'div'], [41, u'span'], [42, u'h1'], [43, u'a'], [44, u'ul'], [45, u'li'], [46, u'a'], [47, u'li'], [48, u'a'], [49, u'li'], [50, u'a'], [51, u'li'], [52, u'a'], [53, u'li'], [54, u'a'], [55, u'li'], [56, u'a'], [57, u'li'], [58, u'a'], [59, u'div'], [60, u'h1'], [61, u'p'], [62, u'strong'], [63, u'strong'], [64, u'strong'], [65, u'strong'], [66, u'strong'], [67, u'p'], [68, u'a'], [69, u'a'], [70, u'p'], [71, u'a'], [72, u'a'], [73, u'a'], [74, u'a'], [75, u'a'], [76, u'a'], [77, u'abbr'], [78, u'p'], [79, u'abbr'], [80, u'a'], [81, u'abbr'], [82, u'div'], [83, u'h1'], [84, u'h2'], [85, u'ul'], [86, u'li'], [87, u'a'], [88, u'li'], [89, u'a'], [90, u'li'], [91, u'a'], [92, u'li'], [93, u'a'], [94, u'li'], [95, u'a'], [96, u'li'], [97, u'a'], [98, u'li'], [99, u'a'], [100, u'h2'], [101, u'ul'], [102, u'li'], [103, u'a'], [104, u'li'], [105, u'a'], [106, u'li'], [107, u'a'], [108, u'li'], [109, u'a'], [110, u'li'], [111, u'a'], [112, u'li'], [113, u'a'], [114, u'li'], [115, u'a'], [116, u'h2'], [117, u'ul'], [118, u'li'], [119, u'a'], [120, u'li'], [121, u'a'], [122, u'li'], [123, u'a'], [124, u'div'], [125, u'p'], [126, u'a'], [127, u'p'], [128, u'span'], [129, u'span'], [130, u'a'], [131, u'a'], [132, u'script']]

list2=[[0, u'html'], [1, u'head'], [2, u'title'], [3, u'link'], [4, u'link'], [5, u'link'], [6, u'link'], [7, u'meta'], [8, u'meta'], [9, u'meta'], [10, u'meta'], [11, u'meta'], [12, u'meta'], [13, u'script'], [14, u'body'], [15, u'ul'], [16, u'li'], [17, u'a'], [18, u'li'], [19, u'a'], [20, u'li'], [21, u'a'], [22, u'li'], [23, u'a'], [24, u'div'], [25, u'a'], [26, u'div'], [27, u'div'], [28, u'form'], [29, u'fieldset'], [30, u'legend'], [31, u'input'], [32, u'input'], [33, u'label'], [34, u'input'], [35, u'input'], [36, u'ul'], [37, u'li'], [38, u'a'], [39, u'li'], [40, u'a'], [41, u'div'], [42, u'span'], [43, u'h1'], [44, u'a'], [45, u'ul'], [46, u'li'], [47, u'a'], [48, u'li'], [49, u'a'], [50, u'li'], [51, u'a'], [52, u'li'], [53, u'a'], [54, u'li'], [55, u'a'], [56, u'li'], [57, u'a'], [58, u'li'], [59, u'a'], [60, u'li'], [61, u'a'], [62, u'div'], [63, u'h1'], [64, u'p'], [65, u'strong'], [66, u'strong'], [67, u'strong'], [68, u'strong'], [69, u'strong'], [70, u'p'], [71, u'a'], [72, u'a'], [73, u'p'], [74, u'a'], [75, u'a'], [76, u'a'], [77, u'a'], [78, u'a'], [79, u'span'], [80, u'a'], [81, u'abbr'], [82, u'p'], [83, u'span'], [84, u'abbr'], [85, u'span'], [86, u'a'], [87, u'div'], [88, u'h1'], [89, u'h2'], [90, u'p'], [91, u'a'], [92, u'h2'], [93, u'ul'], [94, u'li'], [95, u'a'], [96, u'li'], [97, u'a'], [98, u'li'], [99, u'a'], [100, u'li'], [101, u'a'], [102, u'li'], [103, u'a'], [104, u'li'], [105, u'a'], [106, u'li'], [107, u'a'], [108, u'h2'], [109, u'ul'], [110, u'li'], [111, u'a'], [112, u'li'], [113, u'a'], [114, u'li'], [115, u'a'], [116, u'li'], [117, u'a'], [118, u'li'], [119, u'a'], [120, u'li'], [121, u'a'], [122, u'li'], [123, u'a'], [124, u'h2'], [125, u'span'], [126, u'ul'], [127, u'li'], [128, u'a'], [129, u'span'], [130, u'li'], [131, u'a'], [132, u'span'], [133, u'li'], [134, u'a'], [135, u'span'], [136, u'div'], [137, u'p'], [138, u'a'], [139, u'p'], [140, u'span'], [141, u'span'], [142, u'a'], [143, u'a'], [144, u'script']]
```

So in order to evaluate how aligned they are, I use the following code:

```
counter=0
offset=0
aligned_counter=0
for i1,string1 in list1:
    i2=i1+offset #maybe we can vary this if the two strings do not match
    string2=list2[i2][1]
    if string2==string1:
        aligned_counter+=1
    counter+=1

alignment_score=float(aligned_counter)/counter
```

Sow can I align the two lists so that most of the list items are aligned (e.g. [[0,0],[1,1]...[27,28]...[132,144]])? And is there a better way to do this other than varying the offset if the two strings are not equal (given that some times some links from the first list can be missing from the second list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *many* possible formal definitions of "most of the list items are aligned", so you're in for a world of pain ;-)

Here's a way that uses just the standard library.  First I note that the integers in your lists appear to be useless, right?  That is, these assertions succeed:

```
assert [t[0] for t in list1] == range(len(list1))
assert [t[0] for t in list2] == range(len(list2))
```

The first element in each `[integer, string]` pair is just the element's index in the list.  I don't know why they're there, but they just get in the way.  So the code here ignores them:

```
import difflib
s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,
                            [t[1] for t in list1],
                            [t[1] for t in list2])
for b in s.get_matching_blocks():
    print "exact match of length", b.size, "starting at indices", b.a, "and", b.b
```

That displays:

```
exact match of length 3 starting at indices 0 and 0
exact match of length 56 starting at indices 3 and 4
exact match of length 17 starting at indices 59 and 62
exact match of length 3 starting at indices 76 and 80
exact match of length 1 starting at indices 79 and 84
exact match of length 1 starting at indices 80 and 86
exact match of length 2 starting at indices 82 and 87
exact match of length 33 starting at indices 84 and 92
exact match of length 3 starting at indices 117 and 126
exact match of length 2 starting at indices 120 and 130
exact match of length 2 starting at indices 122 and 133
exact match of length 9 starting at indices 124 and 136
exact match of length 0 starting at indices 133 and 145
```

As the docs explain, the final "matching block" returned is always a dummy, of size 0.

`.get_matching_blocks()` implements a kind of "local alignment" (see the general links others gave you).  It may or may not be what you want.  But at least it's already coded for you ;-)

Answer (score 2):

if i understood it correctly, this is the classical sequence alignment problem ( see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment) ). There are straight forward dynamic programming algorithms to obtain sort of "optimal" solution, for example see [Needleman–Wunsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman-Wunsch_algorithm)

Comment: yes, that's sequence alignment, so are there any standard pythonic way of doing this or I need to develop one on my own?

Comment: @hmghaly you can see the pseudo-code on the wiki page, but there may be python implementations already available on the web

Comment: both are Wikipedia articles as far as I can see

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but apparently it has some bug:

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\alignment\profile.py", line 35
    return {e: float(w) / t for e, w in self.__weights.iteritems()}
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax